# javax.validation.constraints Annotation doesn't work when I changed Generation type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

everyone!
I faced with a problem. I have Entity with javax.validation.constraints. And when I change @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) to another. My DAO test stop working. These annotations don't work anymore. Why is it so? Or I miss something?

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resident")
public class Resident {

    @Column(name = "RESIDENT_ID")
    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer residentId;

    @NotNull(message = "First name is a required field")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "First name should be min 2, max 20 symbols")
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "Last name is a required field")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Last name should be min 2, max 20 symbols")
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;
```

my test:

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionCreateWithWrongParamResidentTest() {
    Apartment apartment = new Apartment(100, "CHEAP");
    Resident resident = new Resident("", null, null,
            LocalDate.of(2021, 3, 13),
            LocalDate.of(2021, 3, 23));
    resident.setApartment(apartment);

    entityManager.persist(apartment);
    Assertions.assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> {
        entityManager.persist(resident);
    });
}
```

I have this message:

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected
> javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException to be thrown, but
> nothing was thrown.

When I change it back - everything is okay.

Comment: GenerationType.AUTO means loot of thinks, apperently hibernate considers this case like the id can be set from client side and actually you are setting it up by en empty string "". I think it is some think like this. Try to do that with Null instead "" and you will have the exception if I'm right.

Comment: Thanks you, but it doesn't work. It doesn't matter which GenerationType I use. Except of IDENTITY - everything is ruing. And all javax.validation.constraints annotations don't work. @NotNull too